# Getting empty artifact when deploying react app with azure devops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-devops

I am new to the devops world. So I don't know really know where this question or issue falls exactly in. I used Create react app to build a static site, have repo hosted on azure devops. I proceeded to attempt to make an automated pipeline using azure devops build tools but I think I am messing up somewhere in the process. When the process reaches the archiving and publishing the artifact it just creates an empty folder `B`.

Hosted on VS2017.

This is the order of events in the first agent job:

- npm install (task)
- set environmental varaibles (inline bash script)
- npm build (task)
- Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory): file to create => 
  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
- Publish Artifact: drop => path to publish: 
  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip

Comment: Is your `npm build` outputting the result to `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann! thanks for the prompt response. By this, do you mean the dropdown that is called `Output Variables`?

Comment: No. You're running a command that generates files. The files go somewhere in the file system. Where do those files go? Is that location the same as the location specified in `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`?

Comment: @DanielMann! I was able to solve it by adding /build to the $(Build.binariesDirectory)! But it was because of your first comment that I was able to pinpoint the issue. If you want to add it as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer. Thank you so much!